# how to add my custom jar dependencies to my webapplication?

Tags: maven

I have child project with some dependencies. When I upload this jar to nexus it's ok.
But when I use this jar in my webapplication and I use mvn clean install -U command. Maven create a war, but the child project dependencies isn't in the war lib folder.

What is the problem?

Comment: So the child project is a Maven project and its dependencies are listet in the POM?

Comment: Yes the child is a Maven project, and reflection isi a child project dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `mvn dependency:tree` on the project. Often, the problem is a wrong scope. Make sure the dependencies all have scope `compile`.